# CSS: Complete Animation Before Pausing

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a steady bouncing animation on an icon which repeats every so often.  When I hover over the icon, I want the animation to smoothly complete before becoming paused.

However, try as I might, I am finding this surprisingly difficult to do. Either the element pauses in place, or the transition to the completed state is not smooth.

- `animation-play-state: paused` will freeze the animation in place, but I want it to complete first
- `animation: none` removes the animation which resets the element to its default position, but it is not a smooth transition
- `transition: <stuff>` does not seem to smoothly transition the icon to its default state
- `animation-iteration-count: 1` on hover behaves inconsistently, sometimes doing what I want and other times not

How can I set it so that, when I hover over the icon, the animation completes itself first before pausing?  I feel like I am missing something obvious, but have hit multiple dead ends.

Here is the approximate code I am using.

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  0%   { right: 0; }
  10%  { right: 0.5em; }
  20%  { right: 0; }
  30%  { right: 0.5em; }
  40%  { right: 0; }
  100% { right: 0; }
}

.container {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.container:hover .icon {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="icon">&gt;</span> Some text
</div>
```

Comment: I think that there is no way to do so only with css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned, I don't think this is possible in css alone. I've bashed together a solution with jQuery. The bouncing animation is now a separate class which is added to the icon. At the end of the animation (as detected in the first line bind()) I remove the class, and only add it again if container is not being hovered over (adding it back, with a setTimeOut, will start the animation again).

If the container is being hovered over, then the bouncing class is not added again, but you see another event listener checking for "mouseout" on container, which will add the class back.

Here's the snippet:

```js
$(".icon").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("bouncing");
    
    //if hovering, don't repeat
    if ($(".container").is(":hover")) return;
    
    //else, repeat. setTimeout is necessary for animation to take.
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".icon").addClass("bouncing");
    });
});

$(".container").mouseout(function() {
   $(".icon").addClass("bouncing");
});
```

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  0%   { right: 0; }
  10%  { right: 0.5em; }
  20%  { right: 0; }
  30%  { right: 0.5em; }
  40%  { right: 0; }
  100% { right: 0; }
}

.container {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
}

.bouncing {
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span class="icon bouncing">&gt;</span> Some text
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to get what you want is using `animation-iteration-count: 1;` instead of `animation-play-state: paused;` on the `hover` state, so the animation will not be repeated.

```css
@keyframes bounce {
  0%   { right: 0; }
  10%  { right: 0.5em; }
  20%  { right: 0; }
  30%  { right: 0.5em; }
  40%  { right: 0; }
  100% { right: 0; }
}

.container {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.icon {
  position: relative;
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.container:hover .icon {
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="icon">&gt;</span> Some text
</div>
```